# How to get "columnspan" effect in Excel automation

Tags: c#, excel, automation

I want to make a table header which takes several cells in Excel document. This is my attempt to solve the problem:

```
Excel._Worksheet worksheet;
...
worksheet.get_Range("A1", "F1").Value = "Table Header";
```

The result is that every cell in A1 - F1 interval has "Table Header" value. I need to have the text printed once in A1 - F1 area. Kind of  `colspan` in HTML or `columnspan` in WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To repeat some rows when printing, use the [PageSetup.PrintTitleRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.ipagesetup.printtitlerows.aspx) property of the worksheet.

```
worksheet.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1";
```

To repeat some columns when printing, use the [PageSetup.PrintTitleColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.ipagesetup.printtitlecolumns.aspx) property of the worksheet.

```
worksheet.PageSetup.PrintTitleColumns = "$A:$B";
```